# Setting up a git repository on a server

Tags: git, authentication, repository, github, single-sign-on

I read through the other git questions here but couldn't really follow whether they are trying to do the same thing as I am. So if you find any duplicates, please let me know.

I have a central server with SSO installed. All my machines are connected through the lan to this server. I have also setup a remote git repository on this server. Now what I'd like to do is make the server act as a central repository. All my employees can commit their code to the server and the server pushes it to the remote git repository.

Can someone please help me out with this process? I am new to git and still learning how to use it effectively. So a step-by-step process or an existing document which I can refer to for this?

Also can I integrate it with SSO in any way?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want a howto guide, please share with us your server O/S. Your first question begins with "Also", which begs the question, what is the first question?

Comment: Edited the question. Sorry was a sloppy cut-paste which caused the confusion. Have added the server details in the comment to Niten's response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/de), which is available free for online reading, has a [great chapter on Git on the Server](https://git-scm.com/book/de/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) that should help clarify the options available and what you need to do to make them work.

Answer (score 1):

What type of SSO are you using?

One possible route would be to use git's SSH transport between the workstations and your local server; when you use `ssh://` rather than `git://`, your git server relies on SSH for authentication.  This means you could potentially use any SSH or PAM compatible SSO technology (assuming a Unix/Linux server), or even just SSH public key authentication if that's good enough.

Comment: We have the server set up on a Mac. We are using Atlassian Crowd for the SSO implementation

Comment: Any help on this Niten? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I took a quick look at Atlassian and (unless I've missed something) it doesn't actually seem to support PAM.  If that's correct, then my idea above is bunk.